# Can we use the views in fabric couchdb?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Can we use views for the fabric couch db for rich queries? How can we achieve something like a foreign key concept as the relational database?

Answer (score 0):

I found that currently views are not supported by fabric couchdb yet from https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5528. This would be added in future.